# Script to check watermarks in all pages of multiple PDF documents

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I have huge number of PDF documents, they are being manually checked for watermarks in all pages. Is it possible for this to be automated through scripts. Each page contains only one watermark. It will also be better to return the list of filenames or documents that are not having watermarks in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Watermarks in a pdf will be stored in the OCG object. So you have to ask acrobat if this object is in the pdf and whether it keeps watermarks.

Attach you will find VBS/VBA code which can do that. The Code you can copy over to Notepad and then save it as "FindWatermarks.vbs" on the desktop. Then drag&drop some pdfs on it and the script will tell you if the pdf include watermarks or not. Good luck, Reinhard

PS.: The script works only with Adobe Acrobat $$$ version, not with only Reader!

```
    '// test dropped files for included watermarks
set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
    '// check if files has been dropped on the script
if objArgs.Count < 1 then
        msgbox("Please drag a file on the script")
        WScript.quit
    else
        msgbox("Files Count: "& objArgs.Count &vblf &"Start with file: " & ObjArgs(0))
end if
    '//contact Acrobat
Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
App.show 'comment or take out to work in hidden mode
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI
    '// write needed js code into vbs variable
js  = "var found "&vblf _
    & "var ocgArray = this.getOCGs();" &vblf _
    & "if (ocgArray == null) {      " &vblf _
    & " found = 0;                  " &vblf _
    & " }else{                      " &vblf _
    & " for (var i=0; i < ocgArray.length; i++) {   " &vblf _
    & "     if (ocgArray[i].name == 'Watermark') {  " &vblf _
    & "         found= 1;           " &vblf _
    & "     }else{                  " &vblf _
    & "         found = 0;          " &vblf _
    & "     }                       " &vblf _
    & " }                           " &vblf _
    & " }"

filesWithWm = ""
filesExWm =""
    '//open files via Avdoc and check for watermarks
for i=0 to objArgs.Count - 1
    FileIn = ObjArgs(i)
    If AVDoc.Open(FileIn, "") Then
        'msgbox(FileIn)
        Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc()
        Set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject
        AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript js
        if jso.found = 1 then
            filesWithWm = filesWithWm &FileIn &vblf
        else
            filesExWm = filesExWm &FileIn &vblf
        end if

    end if
next
    '// report found files
if InStr(filesWithWm,":\")>0 then msgbox("Watermarks found:" &vblf & filesWithWm)
if InStr(filesExWm,":\")>0 then msgbox("No Watermarks found:" &vblf & filesExWm)
    '// exit application
App.CloseAllDocs
App.Exit

Set AForm = Nothing
Set JSO = Nothing
Set PDDoc = Nothing
Set AVDoc = Nothing
Set App = Nothing
```

If you need small code changes let me know.